# Button not resizing to fit text (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Sc.kv

```
<Selector>:
    pos: 200, 400

<ScLayout>:
    cols: 2
    pos: self.parent.pos
    spacing: 10

<Button>:
    width: len(self.text) * 50

FloatLayout:
    Selector:
        ScLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'hey'
            Button:
                text: 'welcome'
            Button:
                text: 'hi'
            Button:
                text: 'how are you'
```

and the ScApp.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Selector(Widget): pass

class ScLayout(GridLayout): pass

class ScApp(App):

    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScApp().run()
```

I want the buttons to resize to fit the size of the text, however what happens instead:
[(not enough rep to embed images!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5tZl.png)

Why does this happen?, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [blog post](http://inclem.net/2014/07/05/kivy/kivy_label_text/) covering this among other things. The key is to bind the Button size to track its texture_size.

Comment: If I do `<Button>: width: self.texture_size[0]`, nothing seems to change EDIT: It was because size_hint_x wasn't none on the GridLayout holding it, oops

Answer (score 1):

```
<Selector>:
    pos: 200, 400

<ScLayout>:
    cols: 2
    pos: self.parent.pos
    spacing: 10

<Button>:
    width: len(self.text) * 50

FloatLayout:
    Selector:
        ScLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'hey'
                text_size: self.width, None
                halign:'center'
                

        Button:
            text: 'welcome'
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign:'center'

        Button:
            text: 'hi'
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign:'center'
        Button:
            text: 'how are you'
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign:'center'
```

Comment: please add explanation